# Is it valid to use starts with selector in css?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is it correct to use starts with selector like the following in css ?

Html

```
<div id="row_1">
..
</div>
<div id="row_2">
..
</div>
```

css

```
div[id^='row']  {
 ...
}
```

It seems to work in latest browsers but I am not sure if this allowed or  a w3c Recommendation .
I wish to know this as to learn the best  practice.

Comment: looks fine. but just make row a class?

Comment: If it works, it's allowed. What are you really trying to find out? Browser compatibility? Use cases? Best practice? Please add more detail to your question.

Comment: Why have you stated `.div` which means element with class `div`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These attribute selectors are completely valid. They are [part of CSS Selectors Level 3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings), which has been W3C Recommendation since 2011.

However, these selectors are not very good for the performance (e.g. with `div[id^='row']` browser will perform attribute checking, including string comparison operation, for every `div` element on the page). Using classes should be more universal approach because using `id`s as styling hooks is not the best idea at all.

Comment: CSS3 attribute selectors are supported in IE8, although only by chance. Not that it really matters since the question is asking about the latest browsers.

Comment: Thank you @llya I was reffering to css2 recommendations http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html and was wondering how it worked

Comment: @BoltClock, thanks for correction about IE8. I removed mentioning it from my answer.